# pandas использование shift совместно с условием для каждой группы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'фрукт': ['абрикос', 'груша', 'абрикос', 'груша','вишня', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия', 'франция', 'бельгия', 'албания','португалия', 'франция'],
'id': ['02','02','5', '5','5', '5'],
'месяц': ['март', 'сентябрь', 'январь', 'ПРОПУЩЕНО','январь', 'апрель']        
}
 df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно отобрать строку перед строкой , где `страна = франция`, но предыдущей строкой считаем строки где `страна не албания и не португалия`.

`df[(df.страна=='франция').shift(-1).fillna(False)]` не понимаю как сюда можно добавить условие с игнорированием указанных стран и применить для каждой группы `id`. Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если будут идти подряд две "франции"?

Comment: @strawdog давайте считать, что нужно игнорировать. Но это я сделаю сам удалив дубликаты при помощи drop_duplicates

Comment: а вы не могли бы показать в вопросе, как вы будете удалять дубликаты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я могу только через промежуточный датафрейм решение предложить - предварительно выкидываем строки, которые нам не подойдут, а потом уже делаем `shift`:

```
df1 = df[~df.страна.isin(['албания','португалия'])]
df1[(df1.страна=='франция').shift(-1).fillna(False)]
```

С группировкой вроде бы тоже кажется работает:

```
df1 = df[~df.страна.isin(['албания','португалия'])]
df1.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[(x.страна=='франция').shift(-1).fillna(False)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: как вторую строку вашего решения применить для каждой группы id? Т.к. теоретичсеки может быть группа с одной строкой , где страна будет франция, тогда shift нам вернет строку из другой группы

Comment: а что должно вернутся, если в группе - одна строка и она - франция?

Comment: @formanite Добавил код. У себя пробовал, вроде бы работает. А вообще приводите пример данных в вопросе, который у вас вызывает сомнения